# Can I directly access MySQL from iPhone using MYSQL API?

Tags: iphone, mysql, build

I have developed an iPhone application which needs to access MySQL database on the server. It builds very well on 'iPhone simulator',but when I want to build 'Device' version, it fails with error messages bolow:

ld: warning: in /usr/local/mysql/lib/libmysqlclient.dylib, file was built for i386 which is not the architecture being linked (armv6)

ld: warning: in /usr/local/mysql/lib/libmygcc.a, file was built for unsupported file format which is not the architecture being linked (armv6)

Is it unreachable to access MySQL from iPhone? Or MySQL server library is wrong?

Comment: look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/961742/mysql-c-api-libraries-for-iphone

Answer (score 0):

The library that you are trying to link is not for iPhone. Have you checked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/673300/how-can-i-use-mysql-database-connection-in-iphone-application-useing-cocos2d)?

Comment: I downloaded and copyed the libmysqlclient.a to my project and build it,but it seems dosen't work.

Comment: im not sure. havnt tried it myself. someone in the same question said that u cant use mysql directly.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you just need to grab the mysql connector for C and compile it for armv6 and armv7.  If you don't want to go through the trouble, you can grab the [Objective-C connector for Mysql](http://www.karlkraft.com/index.php/2010/09/17/mysql-for-iphone-and-osx/) that I have written and either use the Objective-C API, or just use included .a file which will work on OSX or iOS.

Comment: Karl, you state on your link that it was not intended for App Store submissions.  Has that changed?